# Context.savechanges is not working Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Here is my code

```
 Using Context As New NotificationManagerEntities1
        Dim User = Context.Users.First()
        User.Firstname = "Shawn"
        User.Lastlogin = Today.Date
        Try
            Context.SaveChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Using
```

This executes fine with no exceptions, but when i look at the table it still has the same orginal value.

Im using a .sdf database with vs 2008

Comment: how do you know there is no exceptions if your swallowing it??

Answer (score 0):

you sure it's not throwing an exception?  your try/catch clause appears to simply swallow the exception without surfacing it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding it to the entity.  You are just creating the object.  You need to call your entities add method.

I'm not a VB guy, so I am not sure on the syntax, but here's how to do it in C#

```
context.MyEntity.Add(newEntity);
```